# How to write a program which would help me to access to data with https in URL

Tags: python-webbrowser

Recently I've been using python to access to web pages with http as the protocol but it is getting out of my hands to access to web pages which have https as their host.Please can someone help to learn the right procedure to solve this error.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to contain specifics: the code you wrote, the issue(s) you're having, expected vs actual output, errors, etc. Otherwise, as written, this is too broad and unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little bit easier, you must use the module requests to access url, but you must especify Not Secure in the settings of your requests.get line, use the argument verify=False

Use the following:

```
r = requests.get('https://m.facebook.com/josue.carranza.56884761', verify=False)
```